# Django Automatic database routing doesn't working

Tags: python, django, routes

I follow doc form django official below
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/multi-db/#automatic-database-routing

I try the Automatic database routing.

my setting is like that

## settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog',
    'zipcode',
]

DATABASES = {
  'default': {},
  'blog': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'testdjango',
    'USER': 'dany',
    'PASSWORD': '****',
  },
  'zipcode': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'zipcode',
    'USER': 'dany',
    'PASSWORD': '****',
   }   
}
DATABASES_ROUTERS = ['blog.router.ZipcodeRouter']
```

## blog/router.py

```
class ZipcodeRouter(object):

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == 'zipcode':
            return 'zipcode'
        return 'blog'

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == 'zipcode':
            return False
        return 'blog'

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if obj1._meta.app_label == 'zipcode' or obj2._meta.app_label == 'zipcode':
            return False
        return 'default'

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if app_label == 'zipcode':
            return False
        return True
```

## blog/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

## zipcode/models.py

```
class Gyeonggi(models.Model):
    new_zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    ...
    old_zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    zipcode_code = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
       managed = False
       db_table = 'gyeonggi'
```

Now I try on QuerySet form python manage.py shell

```
from zipcode.models import Gyeonggi
Gyeonggi.objects.all()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\NPOST\.virtualenvs\django\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 232, in __repr__
    data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
  File "C:\Users\NPOST\.virtualenvs\django\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 256, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\NPOST\.virtualenvs\django\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1087, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "C:\Users\NPOST\.virtualenvs\django\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 54, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql()
  File "C:\Users\NPOST\.virtualenvs\django\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 824, in execute_sql
    sql, params = self.as_sql()
  File "C:\Users\NPOST\.virtualenvs\django\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 369, in as_sql
    extra_select, order_by, group_by = self.pre_sql_setup()
  File "C:\Users\NPOST\.virtualenvs\django\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 46, in pre_sql_setup
    self.setup_query()
  File "C:\Users\NPOST\.virtualenvs\django\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 37, in setup_query
    self.select, self.klass_info, self.annotation_col_map = self.get_select()
  File "C:\Users\NPOST\.virtualenvs\django\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 226, in get_select
    ret.append((col, self.compile(col, select_format=True), alias))
  File "C:\Users\NPOST\.virtualenvs\django\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 353, in compile
    sql, params = node.as_sql(self, self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\NPOST\.virtualenvs\django\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\expressions.py", line 659, in as_sql
    return "%s.%s" % (qn(self.alias), qn(self.target.column)), []
  File "C:\Users\NPOST\.virtualenvs\django\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 344, in quote_name_unless_alias
    r = self.connection.ops.quote_name(name)
  File "C:\Users\NPOST\.virtualenvs\django\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\dummy\base.py", line 21, in complain
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. "
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: **settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentati
on for more details.**
```

After run the QuerySet I got this error.

Thus I check the next.

```
Gyeonggi._meta.app_label
'zipcode'
```

I can find the 'model._meta.app_label' is 'zipcode' but the router.py dosen't work.

I don't want use using('zipcode').

How can I fix it?

Comment: You're setting `DATABASES_ROUTERS`, but you should set `DATABASE_ROUTERS` (no `s` at the end of `database`).

Comment: OMG. I didn't check the spelling that is important.
Thanks @knbk it is work find now.